# Wiriting text into a file from Python

Tags: python-2.7

```
import random
import time
x = 1
def clear():
    print "\n" * 100


while x == 1:
    number1 = random.randrange(1,5)
    number2 = random.randrange(1,13)
    strength = number2/number1+10
    number3 = random.randrange(1,5)
    number4 = random.randrange(1,13)
    skill = number4/number3+10
    clear()
    print 'Hello and Welcome to the Character Charactaristics Machine'
    time.sleep(1)
    clear()
    qname = raw_input("What is your Character's name?:")
    time.sleep(1)
    clear()
    print "We will now determine", qname,"'s Charactaristics"
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print 'Calculating...'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print 'Calculating...'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print 'Calculating...'
    time.sleep(0.5)
    character = (qname,"'s skill level is",skill,"and strength level is" ,strength,)
    print character
    x = 2
    characterdata = open("test.txt", "w")
    characterdata.write(character)
    characterdata.close
```

Im making a program in which you type in a characters name, and its strength and skill levels get generated. I want it so the names and the skill/strength levels of the characters get saved in a sort of database. Im trying to make it so the string 'character'(the details of the character) gets displayed in the test.txt document but it comes up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George\Documents\School Work\Characterisitcs of character the code.py", line 34, in <module>
    characterdata.write(character)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Any Help?, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
character = (qname,"'s skill level is",skill,"and strength level is" ,strength,)
```

The `character` variable is of type tuple not type string, that is why you are getting an error.

I think what you meant to do was this.

```
character = qname + "'s skill level is" + str(skill) + "and strength level is" + str(strength)
```

The above creates a string type variable. This variable can now be written to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Three other possibilities:

```
character = ''.join(map(str, (qname,
                              "'s skill level is ",
                              skill,
                              ' and strength level is ',
                              strength,
                              )))
character = "%s's skill level is %s and strenght level is %s" % (qname, skill, strength)
character = "%(qname)s's skill level is %(skill)s and strength level is %(strength)s" \
            locals()
```

The last variant could be considered best since it is suitable for i18n (it can be translated, including allowing for changing the order).